# Django raise ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i have a problem with raise ValidationError, it won't display if the user writes only 1,2,3 words. If i press submit it shows only the title Contact and the submit button. It should show if user writes under 4 words.

views.py

```
def contact(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, email, ['inbox01@yahoo.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        data['form'] = ContactForm(
            initial={'subject': 'I love your site!'}
        )

    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', data)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, min_length=7)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']
        num_words = len(message.split())
        if num_words < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Not enough words!')
        return message
```

contact_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contact us</h1>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is invalid, you have to add `data['form'] = form` to redisplay the form on the page. Or better, do not use the `data` variable at all:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, email, ['inbox01@yahoo.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm(
            initial={'subject': 'I love your site!'}
        )

    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: ok, it works but i don't understand why it's not working with data['form'] = form

Comment: `data['form'] = form` needs to be exactly below the redirect.